# Test if form element is empty given the form object in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

There is a list of products on one page and each product has a "add to cart" form associated with it. All forms are exactly the same (same name, elements)

Every form has 2 elements, a) Product Id (hidden) b) Booking Date (name=properties[Date])
I want to check if Booking date field is empty before adding product to cart.
I following code is giving an error

```
function addToCart(e){

  if (typeof e !== 'undefined') e.preventDefault();

  var form      = $(this).parents('form');
  if (form[properties[Date]] === "") {
    alert('Please select a date');
    return false;
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/add.js',
    async: false,
    data: form.serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    error: addToCartFail,
    success: addToCartSuccess,
    cache: false
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps?

```
$('form input .dateClass').blur(function(){

    if( !$(this).val() ) {
    alert('Please select a date');
    return false;
    }

}
```

or

```
$('form input #dateId').blur(function() {

    if($(this).val().length === 0) {
    alert('Please select a date');
    return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

parents only gives you direct parents in the DOM tree. Try:

```
if ($('form [name=' + properties[Date] + ']')) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this?

```
if (form.properties.date === "") {
   alert('Please select a date');
   return false;
}
```

'Date' is an Object in Javascript, but by using foo[bar] notation, you are actually trying to get an property of 'foo' with the value stored on a variable called 'bar'.